# Cant find my app on google play

Tags: android, google-play

Hi i just uploaded an application in google play but i cannot find it.

I searched the marker nothing then i searched the google play with my name as a developer and i found only one older application i had uploaded.

Then i tried to search by the package name using

```
http://market.android.com/details?id=[your app package name]
```

and nothing too...any suggestions ?

In developer console everything looks fine and my app is shown as published.

Comment: Be patient, it takes some time.

Answer (score 5):

It takes a while like stated [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html#final-checks):

> When you are ready, click the Publish button in the Developer Console. Within a few hours, your app will become available to users and your product page will be appear in Google Play for browsing, searching, or linking from your promotional campaigns.